# How can i use not or != in nestjs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to compare to ids one in relation and the other given by me in a query and get all information, for example:

```
async getAllPhoto(id: string) {
var photo = await this._photoRepository.find({
      relations: {
        catalogue: true,
      },
      where: { catalogue: { id: Not(id) } },
    });
    return photo;
}
```

I tried this but got an empty array.

Comment: Did you try to log what the `find()` method returns? if it's giving an empty array, it could mean that there are no photos in the database that are not associated with a catalogue that has the given `id` or you could check the data in your DB if there is any photos and catalogues that match your criteria

Comment: i need to show the empty photo also ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to fetch the catalogues that do not have any photos, in which case you'd have to approach it from the other side of the relationship. Do a find on catalogue where id is X and join it to photo. You can either group the catalogues in code or with group by

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ids = 2; // get your id which you request from font-end
const photo = this.repository.find({
  relations:['catalogue'],
  where:{
    catalogue:{
      id: Not(ids)
    }
  }
})
```

when you develop project in nestjs,

you'd better enable "logging":true in your database config!

you will find all raw sql from ORM.

Comment: and where catalogue is null not showed ??

Comment: photo.id != id AND photo=empty or null or undefined, which are not connected to any catalogue

Comment: sir, you find photo object from table maybe named "tbl_photo", so you can't use photo column in your sql! in nestjs(typeorm orm),if you want use where and, keep where parameter is a object, if want where or, keep that parameter is an array